# Proof of the inequality $F_i<(5/3)^i$ for the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: inequality, induction, fibonacci-numbers

The example states:

> As an example, we prove that the Fibonacci numbers, F<sub>0</sub> = 1, F<sub>1</sub> = 1, F<sub>2</sub> = 2, F<sub>3</sub> = 3, F<sub>4</sub> = 5,..., F<sub>i</sub> = F<sub>i - 1</sub> + F<sub>i - 2</sub>, satisfy F<sub>i</sub> < (5/3)<sup>i</sup>, for all i >= 1.  To do this, we first verify that the theorem is true for the trivial cases.  It is easy to verify that F<sub>1</sub> = 1 < 5/3 and F<sub>2</sub> = 2 < 25/9; this proves the basis.  We assume that the theorem is true for i = 1, 2,..., k; this is the inductive hypothesis. To prove the theorem, we need to show that F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>. We have F<sub>k + 1</sub> = F<sub>k</sub> + F<sub>k - 1</sub>

And I got all of that until they started on the the rest of the proof which goes like this:

> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (5/3)<sup>k</sup> + (5/3)<sup>k - 1</sup>

Got that...

> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (3/5)(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup> + (3/5)<sup>2</sup>(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>

Now I'm lost, but the the rest of the math makes sense up until the next to last step.

> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (3/5)(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup> + (9/25)(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>
> which simplifies to
> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (3/5 + 9/25)(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>
> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (24/25)(5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>
> F<sub>k + 1</sub> < (5/3)<sup>k + 1</sup>

The two things I don't understand are how they got to the second step of the proof and how they eliminated the 24/25. I feel really dumb right now. Could some one show me what I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by '2nd part of the proof'? Which exact step don't you understand?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @flawr Sorry I meant the second step in the proof. I'll fix that.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Thanks for fixing the question!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538834/589 for a general approach.

Answer (score 2):

First you can assume that $F_k < (5/3)^k$ and $F_{k-1} < (5/3)^{k-1}$ so.

$$F_{k+1} = \underbrace{F_{k}}_{<(5/3)^k}+\underbrace{F_{k-1}}_{< (5/3)^{k-1}} <(5/3)^k+ (5/3)^{k-1}$$

We can use $24/25 <1$ like so: $$F_{k+1} < \underbrace{24/25}_{<1} \cdot (5/3)^{k+1} <  1 \cdot (5/3)^{k+1}$$

Comment: Alright I think I get the next to last step now. What you're saying is that because 24/25 < 1 it's almost like saying 1(5/3)^(k + 1) due to the inequality. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

To add to flawr's answer; regarding the "2nd part" - they're using the fact that $ 1 = \frac{5}{3} \times \frac{3}{5}$.

So $(\frac{5}{3})^k = \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{5}{3} \times (\frac{5}{3})^k = \frac{3}{5} \times (\frac{5}{3})^{k+1}$

Comment: Okay! Yeah that makes sense now. I see what's going on with that second step in the proof now, but I'm still confused about the 24/25 < 1 step. Could you clarify that for me, please?

Comment: So it's obviously true that $\frac{24}{25} < 1$. We can multiply both sides of that inequality by $(\frac{5}{3})^{k+1}$ to get $\frac{24}{25} \times (\frac{5}{3})^{k+1} < (\frac{5}{3})^{k+1}$ - which is what you need!

Comment: I get it now! I feel really dumb, but I completely get it now. Thank you for your help!