# Induction proof for $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}\leq F(n) \leq 2^n$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I need help with the following task:

The Fibonacci numbers $F(0),F(1),F(2),\dots$ are defined as following:

\begin{align}
F(0) & = 0 \\
F(1) & = 1 \\
F(n) & = F(n-1) + F(n-2) \text{ for }n \geq  2.\end{align}

I have to show that $F(n)\leq 2^n$ for all positive integers. I got this far:

S:$F(2) = 1 \leq 4$

T:$F(n) \geq F(n+1)$
$$F(n) = F(n-2)+F(n-1)\leq 2^n $$
$$F(n+1) = F(n-1)+F(n) \leq 2^{n+1} .$$

I also have to prove that $F(n) \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$, which I have no idea on how to do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am, aren't I?

Comment: Very little. You should use it for **all** mathematical symbols. Besides, in order to get $\leq$ please type `\leq`.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894743/proof-by-induction-nth-fibonacci-number-is-at-most-2n/1538834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $k\leqslant n\implies F(k)\leqslant2^k$. Then$$F(n+1)=F(n)+F(n-1)\leqslant2^n+2^{n-1}\leqslant2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}.$$On the other hand, let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $k\leqslant n\implies F(k)\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}$. Then\begin{align}F(n+1)&=F(n)+F(n-1)\\&\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac32\right)^{n-2}\\&=\left(\frac32+1\right)\left(\frac32\right)^{n-2}\\&\geqslant\frac94\left(\frac32\right)^{n-2}\\&=\left(\frac32\right)^n.\end{align}