# simplify rational expression with negative exponent.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking trying to follow a solution and am failing to understand the following simplification.

Can someone please break the working out down into the smallest steps to help me understand. How do they get from $(\frac{7}{4})^{n-1} + (\frac{7}{4})^{n-2}$ to that being equal to
$(\frac{7}{4})^{n-2}\{\frac{7}{4} + 1\}$  and what is with the curly braces? The rest of the solution I understand.

any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{n-2}=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{n-2}\cdot\frac{7}{4}+\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{n-2}=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{n-2}\left(\frac{7}{4}+1\right)$, where the first equality is due to $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$ applied to $a=\frac{7}{4}$, $b=n-2$, and $c=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722202/if-f-n-is-the-fibonacci-sequence-show-that-f-n-left-frac-74-rightn-fo

Comment: Curly braces are just another way to group terms, just like parentheses. Why someone uses curly braces instead of parentheses is a matter of style, there is no change in mathematical content.

Comment: thanks a bunch @ jyre that's what I was missing. the excellent explanation with the variables a,b,c was super helpful.

Comment: but how does the n-1 magically turn into n-2?

Answer (score 1):

Treat the curly brackets as ordinary brackets and factor out $\left(\frac74\right)^{n-2}$:

$\quad\left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-1} + \left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-2} \\= \left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-2}\times \dfrac74 + \left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-2}\times 1 \\=\left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-2}\times \left(\dfrac74+1\right) \\=\left(\dfrac74\right)^{n-2}\times \left(\dfrac{11}4\right)$