# help on: $f_{n+1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n}, n\geq 1$

Tags: induction

Just wanted to ask if someone could help me with this proof: $f_{n+1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n}, n\geq 1$, where $f_{n+1} = f_{n}+f_{n-1}.$ The base case where $n=1$ is straightforward. I wrote down an induction hypothesis:

$f_{k+1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k},$ for some $k\geq 1.$

Induction step: By induction this implies that: $f_{k+2}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.$

I started the proof with the induction hypothesis: $f_{k+1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k},$ and deduced from there that: $f_{k+1}+f_{k}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k}+f_{k},$ which is: $f_{k+2}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k}+f_{k}.$ (By definition of a Fibonacci number.)

I then tried to show that if: $(\frac{7}{4})^{k}+f_{k}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)},$ then this must imply that: $f_{k+2}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.$

Comment: I would try to use strong induction.  That is, assuming that for all $1<=n<=k$ for some $k$, that $f(n)<(7/4)^n$.  When you make your induction step, you now have a geometric progression which you can work with.

Comment: Strong induction is indeed the better course of action. You'll need to prove two base cases: $f_2 < \frac{7}{4}$ and $f_3 < \frac{49}{16}$. You can then assume that $f_k < \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-1}$ and $f_{k-1} < \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2}$. This tells you, by assumption, $f_{k+1} = f_k + f_{k-1} < \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-1} + \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2}$. See if you can conclude from this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence, show that $F_n &lt; \left(\frac 74\right)^n$ for $n\geq 1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722202/if-f-n-is-the-fibonacci-sequence-show-that-f-n-left-frac-74-rightn-fo) - found through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f_%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Clt(%5Cfrac%7B7%7D%7B4%7D)%5En%24&p=1). There also other duplicates (sometimes closed as dups.), e.g., [Prove $F_{n+1} ≤ (\frac74)^n $, where $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers](/q/2951228), [Prove using mathematical induction](/q/3940733), etc.