# $f_{n+1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n}, n\geq 1.$

Tags: solution-verification, fibonacci-numbers

Here is my proof of the statement: $f_{(n+1)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n}, n\geq 1$.

Note: $f_{(n+1)}$ and etc. denote the Fibonacci numbers, and hence each term is the sum of the previous two terms, so: $f_{(n+1)} = f_{(n)}+f_{(n-1)}.$

Base case: LHS: $f_{2} = 1$, RHS: $(\frac{7}{4}),$ so $1<(\frac{7}{4}).$

Induction Hypothesis: Let us assume $f_{(k+1)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k}$, for some $k>1.$

Induction step: By the principle of induction, this implies that: $f_{(k+2)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.$

Proof:

We assumed that: $f_{(k+1)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{k}$, for some $k>1.$

This then implies that: \begin{align}(\frac{7}{4})f_{(k+1)}&<(\frac{7}{4})(\frac{7}{4})^{k}\\
&=(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.
\end{align}

If we can show that, $(\frac{7}{4})f_{(k+1)}>f_{(k+2)}$, for $k>1$ then, we have shown that: $f_{(k+2)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.$

\begin{align}
(\frac{7}{4})f_{(k+1)}&>f_{(k+2)}\\
(\frac{7}{4})f_{(k+1)}&>f_{(k+1)}+f_{(k)}\\
(\frac{3}{4})f_{(k+1)}&>f_{(k)}.\\
\end{align}

Hence, since this inequality is true for $k>1,$ this implies that: $f_{(k+2)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{(k+1)}.$

Hence, by induction we have proven that: $f_{(n+1)}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n}, n\geq 1$.

Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775590/use-induction-to-show-that-for-all-positive-integers-n-f-n-%e2%89%a4-1-75n)

Comment: Quote from https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info : For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: "$(\frac{3}{4})f_{(k+1)}>f_{(k)}$ [...] this inequality is true for $k>1$": Uh?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I doubt the link helps.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538834/589